# Do I need a background job to consume messages from Kafka?

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, micronaut

Is it necessary to run a background job to continuously consume messages from Kafka's topic?

I'm trying to write an application using Micronaut in Kotlin as `Kafka Consumer`, is there any way to consume messages from Kafka without running a background job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need implement a background job yourself. Leave this to the framework.

All you need to do is define a Micronaut bean as a `KafkaListener`. The [documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-kafka/latest/guide/#kafkaListener) states as follows:

> Using the @KafkaListener annotation Micronaut will build a KafkaConsumer and start the poll loop by running the KafkaConsumer in a special consumer thread pool

So what you should do is

```kotlin
@KafkaListener
class MyKafkaListener {

    @Topic("topic-you-want-to-listen-to")
    fun receive(@KafkaKey brand: String, name: String) { 
      // implement your listener
    }
}
```

Hope this helps as a brief clarification.